# Does Magento 2.4.6 SMTP work with Amazon SES?

Tags: aws, smtp, magento2.4.6

One of the great new features of 2.4.6 is the out-of-the-box SMTP functionality. However I haven't been able to get it to work with my Amazon SES credentials. Am I correct in asuming that Magento does not support this yet and I have to add this functionality or am I missing something?